# STM32 CLI Prompts To Command Line (Python)

Tags: python-2.7, subprocess, microcontroller, stm32, os.system

I am so lost on how to achieve this.. It seems so simple in theory, but I've tried everything I can think of and all the related examples I understand..

So, i'm trying to automate the process of flashing a micro controller and found I can use the STM32 Link CLI in the command prompt rather than the utility app (where you have to click each button individually). My hope is to incorporate this into my Python code where I test the board I am flashing to fully automate the entire process.

I've only started coding this year so I'm a bit new at this... I am able to type this into the command terminal:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\STMicroelectronics\STM32 ST-LINK Utility\ST-LINK Utility\ST-LINK_CLI.exe" -c -p "C:\Users\Desktop\TempCtrl.bin" -Rst -Run
```

Which flashes it proper, but I can't seem to replicate this line within Python:

```
os.system('"C:\Program Files (x86)\STMicroelectronics\STM32 ST-LINK Utility\ST-LINK Utility\ST-LINK_CLI.exe" -c -p "C:\Users\Desktop\TempCtrl.bin" -Rst -Run')
```

Doesn't seem to do anything...

I've tried using subprocess as I've seen its a powerful tool, but can't seem to find out how to use it in this instance.. Progress so far:

```
p = Popen(['ST-LINK_CLI.exe'], stdout=PIPE, stdin=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, shell=True)
stdout_data = p.communicate(input='enter')[0]
```

It reads out "ValueError: I/O operation on closed file" if I try anything else.
Thank you for any and all help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out!

```
import subprocess
subprocess.check_output(['C:\Program Files (x86)\STMicroelectronics\STM32 ST-LINK Utility\ST-LINK Utility\ST-LINK_CLI.exe', '-c', '-p', 'C:\Users\Desktop\TempCtrl.bin', '0x08000000', '-V', '-Rst', 'Run'])
```

This  seems to do the trick. The CLI software manual isn't very descriptive on some points, but it is imperative to add the hex address as it didn't work without it. Full automation here I come! Hope this helps someone in automating their flash process as well!

Comment: Great. Just to confirm which interface are using to flash the board. because i think after -c we should give interface type. that as following

Comment: "C:\Program Files (x86)\STMicroelectronics\STM32 ST-LINK Utility\ST-LINK Utility\ST-LINK_CLI.exe" -c SWD -p "C:\Users\Desktop\TempCtrl.bin" -Rst -Run

Comment: Oh! Thank you for pointing that out dev_eng. It does default to SWD, but for clarity it would have been better for me to have added it.